# "even more", "even much more", "many more"

Tags: expression-choice

My sentence is this:

> Parents teach us how to speak and interact in social situations **and even more**.

I would like to know how to say ***"and a lot of other things"*** at the end of my sentence.

I have some suggestions, but I don't know which one is better:

> **"... and even more."**
>
> **"... and even much more."**
>
> **"... and many more."**

Comment: Yes, I wrote it.

Comment: Why don't you go with ***"much more besides"***?

Comment: I understand that your version is correct, but I want to know which one is a synonym to that, or which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: If you want to say "and a lot of other things", why don't you. Do you have to pay for extra words?

Answer (score 0):

Many more *what?* Situations? It's unclear that many more situations in which you can speak and interact actually exist. But assuming that they do, you need to write carefully to remove the ambiguity. Perhaps something like

> Parents teach us how to speak and interact in a myriad of situations, including social situations.

Comment: No, I wanted to write, that parents teach us how to speak, how to interact in social situations, and they teach us a lot of other things too.

Comment: Ah! Well as I said, the sentence was quite ambiguous. So what is wrong with what you just wrote in your comment? "parents teach us how to speak, how to interact in social situations, and many other things besides."

Comment: In the original sentence I wanted to write it shorter, and I don't know which form is correct for the meaning "and many other things besides" in your last sentence?

Comment: So does even more, even much more or many more correct, if I want to achieve the same meaning?

Comment: Not really; in my opinion all of those are ambiguous and unclear.

Comment: Okay, but could you tell me then, what the original suggestions mean? For example in a sentence, or how can I use them?

Answer (score 0):

Since you the "many other things" you refer to have nothing to do with speaking or interacting socially, I would use a longer sentence, not just a couple of words. You want to list things parents teach: speak, interact, and do other things.

> Parents teach us how to speak, interact in social situations, and do many other things.

The word 'do' above can be omitted if some the teachings you refer do not imply direct action.

Answer (score -1):

Parents teach us to speak and interact not only in social situations but many more.

I hope that helps

Comment: No, I wanted to write, that parents teach us how to speak, how to interact in social situations, and they teach us a lot of other things too.